# Compile-time check for vector dimension

Tags: scala, types

I am implementing some lightweight mathematical vectors in scala. I would like to use the type system to check vector compatibility at compile time. For example, trying to add a vector of dimension 2 to another vector of dimension 3 should result in a compile error.

So far, I defined dimensions as case classes:

```
sealed trait Dim
case class One() extends Dim
case class Two() extends Dim
case class Three() extends Dim
case class Four() extends Dim
case class Five() extends Dim
```

And here is the vectors definition:

```
class Vec[D <: Dim](val values: Vector[Double]) {

  def apply(i: Int) = values(i)

  def *(k: Double) = new Vec[D]( values.map(_*k) )

  def +(that: Vec[D]) = {
    val newValues = ( values zip that.values ) map { 
      pair => pair._1 + pair._2
    }
    new Vec[D](newValues)
  }

  override lazy val toString = "Vec(" + values.mkString(", ") + ")"

}
```

This solution works well, however I have two concerns:

- How can I add a `dimension():Int` method that returns the dimension (ie. 3 for a `Vec[Three]`)?
- How can I handle higher dimensions without declaring all the needed case classes in advance ?

**PS:** I know there are nice existing mathematical vector libs, I am just trying to improve my scala understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestions:

- [Peano Numbers](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/type-level-programming-in-scala-part-4a-peano-number-basics/) by Apocalysp (link to part a, other parts follow)
- [Church Numerals](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2008/11/practical-church-numerals-in-scala.html) by Jim McBeath

Comment: Aaahhh, the joys of type-level programming.

Comment: Yes but to solve my problem, how can I "convert" a peano type to an Int and how can I build automatically the correct peano type corresponding to a given Int ?

Comment: @paradigmatic You can't do Int -> Peano. That requires dependent types, which is not supported by Scala. Converting Peano to Int it trivial and left as an exercise to the reader. ;-) For languages that do support dependent types, see Agda and Coq.

Answer (score 1):

I's suggest something like this:

```
sealed abstract class Dim(val dimension:Int)

object Dim {
  class One extends Dim(1)
  class Two extends Dim(2)
  class Three extends Dim(3)

  implicit object One extends One
  implicit object Two extends Two
  implicit object Three extends Three
}

case class Vec[D <: Dim](values: Vector[Double])(implicit dim:D) {

  require(values.size == dim.dimension)

  def apply(i: Int) = values(i)

  def *(k: Double) = Vec[D]( values.map(_*k) )

  def +(that: Vec[D]) = Vec[D](
     ( values zip that.values ) map {
      pair => pair._1 + pair._2
  })

  override lazy val toString = values.mkString("Vec(",", ",")")
}
```

Of course you can get only a *runtime* check on the vector length that way, but as others pointed already out you need something like Church numerals or other typelevel programming techniques to achieve compile time checks.

```
  import Dim._
  val a = Vec[Two](Vector(1.0,2.0))
  val b = Vec[Two](Vector(1.0,3.0))
  println(a + b)
  //--> Vec(2.0, 5.0) 

  val c = Vec[Three](Vector(1.0,3.0)) 
  //--> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  //-->        at scalatest.vecTest.main(vecTest.scala)
  //--> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to go down the Peano route, you could always have your `Vec` be constructed with a `D` and then use the instance for determine the dimension via the `Dim` companion object. For instance:

```
object Dim {
  def dimensionOf(d : Dim) = d match {
    case One => 1
    case Two => 2
    case Three => 3
  }
}
sealed trait Dim
```

I think for choice, you should be using case objects rather than case classes:

```
case object One extends Dim
case object Two extends Dim
```

Then on your vector, you might have to actually store the Dim:

```
object Vec {
  def vec1 = new Vec[One](One)
  def vec2 = new Vec[Two](Two)
  def vec3 = new Vec[Three](Three)
}

class Vec[D <: Dim](d : D) {
  def dimension : Int = Dim dimensionOf d
  //etc
```